# Open Aource application/protocol for internet applications

Tags: protocols, tcp

In near future I'll need to start working on a new project that consist of highly loaded TCP/IP servers and clients that communicate to that server. I know the basics of TCP/IP and can make the server and clients talk over the wire.

The problem is that I need to find some ways to protect server against other "clients" that can send bogus data and may crash the server. I'm looking for any ideas or recommendations for an application-level protocol that I can use for my application. Pretty sure there must be some kind of open-source MMORPG game that has already implemented such a protocol.

Any other ideas are very welcome.

P.S. I have checked already the [WorldForge project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WorldForge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use authentication and write your server so that bogus data doesn't crash it. You can also utilize firewalls where appropriate.

Have a look at http://www.devmaster.net/ for game development. I've read many useful articles there.

Comment: yeah, nicely said, of course I do have authentication. I just need a correct way to write the server, and really don't want to reinvent the wheel. But as I can from other forums as well, people are not willing to share such type of code, any code for nubs welcome, something more sophisticated everyone want money, lol

Comment: How do you have authentication implemented? Have you tried debugging the crashes you speak of? Without more details about your project/problem, I'm afraid that is the best advice. Why not start by telling us the nature of your application, what language you are implementing it in, and what kind of network you will deploy it on.

Comment: I didn't start it yet. Just collecting information on how to build a robust tcp/ip server that could handle at least 5000 clients and be error prone to external bogus clients. Language to be used is C#. The application itself will be data broadcaster. Basically every client will subscribe to some kind of information, and when is available the server will send it to needed client. clients will connect to server over internet.

Comment: What I said still applies. Authentication, robust/elegant code, firewalls. Logging is important too. For example if one client is continually causing problems. I hope you do know how TCP/IP works. Because a server can't just send data to a client unless the client has established a connection first. So really, you'll need the clients to check periodically. Why not use JSONRPC? There are probably lots of implementations to take a look at for ideas. I wrote one in PHP.

Comment: the reason I asked is that maybe has written already a robust/elegant code that is extend-able to different scenarios. Can't use JSON, need fast data sending mechanism, for lots of binary data.

Comment: oh, actually the major reason I asked, is too see how the "big guys" are handling binary data records in tcp/ip servers. Trying to avoid common mistakes and reduce debugging time :)

Comment: There are lots of robust/elegant solutions. You need to ask a more specific question if you want a more specific answer. "Data records" sound like they are from a database. Are you storing lots of binary data in a database?

Comment: show me a couple of them. by data record I mean a "public class MyObject" that needs to be serialized and send over the wire.

Comment: ok, to be simple, does anybody know any open source project that would use tcp/ip server for multiple connections and data broadcasting, like an online games or something.

Comment: I can tell you right off the bat, you are gonna take a performance hit serializing and passing around objects. Games usually have minimal overhead in this(any?) area. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: thx for the link, but this makes my assumption even more stable. You can find bunch of articles and tutorials about painting, and none about tcp/ip servers and communication protocols, it looks like this is a very high tech or something like :)

Comment: I'm going to end this useless comment section with this: With your attitude your application will never be complete. You need to put in some effort. It looks there are at least 13 engines that fit your requirements: http://www.devmaster.net/engines/search.php

Comment: well thx for help anyway. the last link was the most useful. Just wondering why there are some many advanced topics for OpenGL and only Hello World samples for networking. That confuses me.

Comment: It's because networking is relatively simple compared to 3D math. If you want examples, I'd recommend taking a look at the source code for some open source games. There are a lot out there. One I play is Xonotic.

Comment: that's http://exitgames.com/Photon what I was looking for. Too bad is not open-source :)