# TCP / Server I can from another class call the components of Form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have this example as a server.
The question that only works well for me on console.
I want to pass it to windows Form. And I don't know how to apply it.

Because I understand that it is bad practice from another class such as creating a `Form1` Method and using a `Form1` object in the `Server` class.

As if in the `Server` class I call the textbox or things like that.

The question that I think I would have to adapt all the code back for windows Form?

Or stop using the classes and use the typical `TcpClient`, `TpcListener` as in the videos that declare it at the moment in Form1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Chatroom
{

    delegate void MessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);

    class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; private set; }

        public MessageEventArgs(string message)
        {
            this.Message = message;
        }
    }

    class Server
    {
        private TcpListener serverSocket;
        private List<Worker> workers = new List<Worker>();

        public Server(int port)
        {
            //serverSocket = new TcpListener(port);// deprecated
            // the same way
            serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            serverSocket.Start();
        }

        private void WaitForConnection()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient socket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Worker worker = new Worker(socket);
                AddWorker(worker);
                worker.Start();
            }
        }

        private void Worker_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(sender as Worker, e.Message);
        }

        private void Worker_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveWorker(sender as Worker);
        }

        private void AddWorker(Worker worker)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                workers.Add(worker);
                worker.Disconnected += Worker_Disconnected;
                worker.MessageReceived += Worker_MessageReceived;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveWorker(Worker worker)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                worker.Disconnected -= Worker_Disconnected;
                worker.MessageReceived -= Worker_MessageReceived;
                workers.Remove(worker);
                worker.Close();
            }
        }

        private void BroadcastMessage(Worker from, String message)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                message = string.Format("{0}: {1}", from.Username, message);
                for (int i = 0; i < workers.Count; i++)
                {
                    Worker worker = workers[i];
                    if (!worker.Equals(from))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            worker.Send(message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            workers.RemoveAt(i--);
                            worker.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class Worker
        {
            public event MessageEventHandler MessageReceived;
            public event EventHandler Disconnected;
            private readonly TcpClient socket;
            private readonly Stream stream;
            public string Username { get; private set; } = null;

            public Worker(TcpClient socket)
            {
                this.socket = socket;
                this.stream = socket.GetStream();
            }

            public void Send(string message)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            public void Start()
            {
                new Thread(Run).Start();
            }

            private void Run()
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2018];
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int receivedBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (receivedBytes < 1)
                            break;
                        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
                        if (Username == null)
                            Username = message;
                        else
                            MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message));
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException) { }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
                Disconnected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            public void Close()
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Server server = new Server(3393);
                server.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (IOException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this. If I have `Form1`.

As I relate it, as I do eg. Every time a new Client is created it is added by a `ListBox` from the `Server` class. In theory you can't or if you can or is it bad practice?

```
Class Server{
private void RemoveWorker(Worker worker)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                **textbox.text +="Cliente desconectado";**
                worker.Disconnected -= Worker_Disconnected;
                worker.MessageReceived -= Worker_MessageReceived;
                workers.Remove(worker);
                worker.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

How could it be done without being in the main WinForm class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code relevant to your problem within the question body; you're more likely to receive assistance that way!

Comment: You `Main()` does not look like it is from WinForms.  If you create a new WinForms project you will get the `Main()` that looks like this ```[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }```

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to help you start.

1. Create a new `WinForms` project in VisualStudio.
2. You project should build and show the form right away without you having to do anything.
3. You should have `Program.cs` that contains the `Main()` method.  You do not need to change it.  This is what causes the `Form1` to load and display.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

4. You can right-click on the `Form1.cs` and select `View Code` to see the code behind page.
5. There you will have the constructor that has `InitializeComponent()` method that creates all of your GUI "stuff".
6. Add a listener to run when the Form loads.  This is where you can add your server stuff.
7. Open your GUI designer, go to `Form1`->`Properties` and add a new function to the `Load`
   [image: Load event]
8. This is where you will write your code.  For example, you can create and start the server.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Server server = new Server(3393);
        server.WaitForConnection();
    }
    catch (IOException) { // Put something here like a log }
}
```

9. Your server can go to a new Class that can be in a new file like `Server.cs`.  Just make sure that `WaitForConnection()` is `public`.

This should get you started.  When you run into an issue, just create a new question on SO and make sure to add your latest code.

Some suggestions:

- Use a `delegate` to communicate between Server and the GUI
- You may want to run the Server in another thread.  Test it first to get it working and see if this is what you need/want
- You don't normally want to run a server as WinForms project.  If you accidently close the form, you kill your server.
- Make sure to have a `Form1_Close` event and shut down your server there correctly